# VS Code does not open any Window when logged in from a Windows PC, but does so, when logged in from Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code on our Debian server.
When I am logged into the server from my Mac and I type "code test.txt" the VSCode window opens with the given text file.
When any user is logged in from their windows PC (with Putty & Xming), the "code test.txt" command does not open any window. Other programs launch Windows easily.

So as an example I ran the command "code code.log --verbose" and this is the output I got:

```
[1005271:0913/112607.047939:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.128Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Request to start watching: /home/heinze/.config/Code/User (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>),/home/heinze/.config/Code/User/settings.json (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>)
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.137Z] Starting VS Code
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.137Z] from: /usr/share/code/resources/app
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.137Z] args: {
  _: [ '/home/heinze/code.log' ],
  diff: false,
  merge: false,
  add: false,
  goto: false,
  'new-window': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  wait: false,
  help: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  'pre-release': false,
  version: false,
  verbose: true,
  status: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  'no-cached-data': false,
  'prof-v8-extensions': false,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  'disable-gpu': false,
  'disable-chromium-sandbox': false,
  'ms-enable-electron-run-as-node': false,
  telemetry: false,
  debugRenderer: false,
  'enable-smoke-test-driver': false,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'skip-welcome': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'disable-keytar': false,
  'disable-workspace-trust': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'crash-reporter-id': 'dcb7898e-cbb1-4a44-a06a-ad4b7606663d',
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  'unity-launch': false,
  'open-url': false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  force: false,
  'do-not-sync': false,
  trace: false,
  'force-user-env': false,
  'force-disable-user-env': false,
  'open-devtools': false,
  'disable-gpu-sandbox': false,
  '__enable-file-policy': false,
  'enable-coi': false,
  'no-proxy-server': false,
  'no-sandbox': false,
  nolazy: false,
  'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
  'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
  'allow-insecure-localhost': false,
  'disable-dev-shm-usage': false,
  'profile-temp': false,
  logsPath: '/home/heinze/.config/Code/logs/20230913T112607'
}
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.138Z] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.138Z] Resolved machine identifier: d1a7f5f6babb7f599fa020d9721d9495b2b0102714c7dc8672f5253267742284
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.138Z] Main->SharedProcess#connect
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.140Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Started watching: '/home/heinze/.config/Code/User'
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.142Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Started watching: '/home/heinze/.config/Code/User/settings.json'
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.143Z] StorageMainService: creating application storage
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.144Z] ElectronURLListener: waiting for window to be ready to handle URLs...
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.144Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 2)
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.144Z] windowsManager#open
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.145Z] windowsManager#open pathsToOpen [
  {
    fileUri: c {
      scheme: 'file',
      authority: '',
      path: '/home/heinze/code.log',
      query: '',
      fragment: '',
      _formatted: null,
      _fsPath: null
    },
    type: 1,
    exists: true,
    options: { selection: undefined }
  }
]
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.146Z] IPC Object URL: Registered new channel vscode:3b6218ed-c4a0-465a-b2f4-9a3310f50c8e.
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.146Z] window#validateWindowState: validating window state on 1 display(s) { mode: 1, x: 1337, y: 294, width: 1024, height: 768 }
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.146Z] window#validateWindowState: 1 monitor working area { x: 0, y: 0, width: 2560, height: 1440 }
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.146Z] window#ctor: using window state { mode: 1, x: 1337, y: 294, width: 1024, height: 768 }
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.180Z] window#load: attempt to load window (id: 1)
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.184Z] windowsManager#open used window count 1 (workspacesToOpen: 0, foldersToOpen: 0, emptyToRestore: 0, emptyToOpen: 0)
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.184Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 3)
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.184Z] resolveShellEnv(): skipped (VSCODE_CLI is set)
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:07.184Z] update#setState idle
[1005271:0913/112608.015206:WARNING:bus.cc(644)] Bus::SendWithReplyAndBlock took 1001ms to process message: type=method_call, path=/org/freedesktop/DBus, interface=org.freedesktop.DBus, member=StartServiceByName
[1005271:0913/112608.015250:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.StartServiceByName: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:11.351Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 4)
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.390Z] IPC Object URL: Removed channel vscode:3b6218ed-c4a0-465a-b2f4-9a3310f50c8e.
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.391Z] Lifecycle#window.on('closed') - window ID 1
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.391Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown.fire()
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.391Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown - begin 'instanceLockfile'
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.392Z] storageMainService#onWillShutdown()
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.392Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown - begin 'applicationStorage'
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.392Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown - begin 'extHostStarter'
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.392Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown - end 'extHostStarter'
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.392Z] Lifecycle#app.on(window-all-closed)
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.392Z] Lifecycle#app.on(before-quit)
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.392Z] Lifecycle#onBeforeShutdown.fire()
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.392Z] [WindowsStateHandler] onBeforeShutdown {
  lastActiveWindow: undefined,
  lastPluginDevelopmentHostWindow: undefined,
  openedWindows: []
}
[main 2023-09-13T09:26:13.392Z] Lifecycle#app.on(will-quit) - begin
```

Comment: interestingly, I don't get any good results by googling `github vscode issues "org.freedesktop.DBus.StartServiceByName"`. It might be a good idea to raise an issue ticket (You can use Help > Report Issue in VS Code). If you do, please link me to your issue ticket.

Comment: I am not sure how I can link/assign you to the issue. You can find the Issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/193466

Answer (score 0):

This was raised as an issue ticket: [VS Code does not open any Window when logged in from a Windows PC, but does so, when logged in from Mac
#193466](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/193466), where [the response from the maintainers](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/193466#issuecomment-1726975356) ([deepak1556](https://github.com/deepak1556)) was:

> This is an issue in the runtime which we cannot address, please use our remote development suite to connect with your server https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh